# Mocking methods of local scope objects with Mockito2.7

Tags: java, jersey, mockito

We are using Maven, Jersey, Mockito 2 in our project. The Mockito 2.7.5 with PowerMockito 1.7.4 dependency is causing some issues: Unable to Mock method of local scope variable. Here is my sample code:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
public Class Sample{
public String method1(String input){
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    InputDO inputDO = mapper.readValue(input, InputDO.class);
    }
}


Inside Test Class

@Test
public void testMethod(){
    ObjectMapper mapper = Mockito.mock(ObjectMapper.class);
    InputDO = inputDO = Mockito.mock(InputDO.class);
    doReturn(inputDO).when(mapper).readValue(anyString(), eq(InputDO.class));
    Sample s = Mockito.mock(Ssample.class);
    s.method1(anyString());
    assertNotNull(s);
}
```

The Test is failing in mapper.raedValue(). Please help me in mocking the above steps.

Comment: can you share your Test class as well?

Comment: also the exact version of mockito and powermockito

Answer (score 0):

Test Fail because you create an Mock for ObjectMapper in Test Class but here Every time new ObjectMapper was creating with new keyword. So better will be

```
`class Test{
ObjectMapper ObjectMapperMock = new ObjectMapper();
ObjectMapper spymapper=spy(ObjectMapperMock);
doReturn(result).when(spymapper.readValue());
}
```

`

Comment: ObjectMapper is a local variable to testMethod() and I can't change the Sample Class

Comment: Then Instead of using Mock use the Spy

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you:

**1)** Annotate test class with:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(ObjectMapper.class)
```

**2)** Add this as the first lines to you test method:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = Mockito.mock(ObjectMapper.class);
PowerMockito.whenNew(ObjectMapper.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(mapper);
```

Comment: If I add powemock-api-mockito 1.7.4 as dependency then all tests are failing. Might be because I'm using Mockito 2.7.

Comment: for 2.7 you need powermock 1.7.0 -> https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito